# What crime(s) was Deedee Blanchard guilty of, and what sentences do they carry (in any jurisdictions)?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, any-jurisdiction, sentencing, child-abuse

Deedee Blanchard was found to have been [murdered](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Dee_Dee_Blanchard) by her daughter and her boyfriend. The daughter was going to receive 30 years imprisonment but upon the court hearing of the crimes to which she has been subjected by her mother which presented the backdrop to Deedee’s murder, they reduced this to 10 years for Gypsy Rose.

Does this suggest that in some sense or other, the crimes of Deedee against her daughter were somehow “worth” 20 years of imprisonment?

Regardless, if Deedee’s abuse of Gypsy Rose had occurred in any given jurisdiction (first and foremost her own in the US), what would she have been guilty of, and what sort of sentences might she have expected to receive?

I’m most  interested in the likely sentences in the U.S., including any states folks may especially know about, and then England & Wales, and then any other European or other global jurisdictions.

---

It’s really hard to encapsulate the extent of the depravity of Deedee’s abuse of her daughter, but it amounted to insisting to her and to society that she was terminally ill and spuriously subjecting her to copious harmful medical treatments, not allowing her to stand or  walk out of her wheelchair, socialise, live normally, and forcing her to be very malnourished.

Comment: Could you please link to reporting of the case rather than assume we know the facts?

Comment: @hszmv it was a very high profile case that received much attention and coverage. I could easily link to WP as I just have, but I don’t really see the benefit because each information resource about the case will cover slightly different aspects so I don’t really know which are the most relevant. It’s a case that’s sort of hard to really summarise, other than watching some of the documentaries which are very shocking. It was a string of abuse that lasted the entire twenty odd years of Gypsie’s life until that point.

Comment: Why do you believe the daughter "was going to receive 30 years imprisonment"?

Comment: @bdb484 not sure, when I first found out about the case I consumed a fair amount of materials about it. One of them explained that they were at first tied together but then when it came to light that GR had been so victimised by her mother the trials were basically Separated. It said that both were supposed to get 30y but then when the trials were separated GR had hers reduced to 10.

Answer (score 1):

I am addressing only a detail of the question, but I think it is important.

> Does this suggest that in some sense or other, the crimes of Deedee against her daughter were somehow “worth” 20 years of imprisonment?

No.

For most countries(*) criminal procedures are not a matter of revenge or settling the scores. They are not something between the criminal who caused the damage and the victim who suffered the damage, but between the criminal who broke a law and the state that established that law and wants it enforced.

The opinion of the victim is, theoretically(*2), not important. It does not matter if they pardon the criminal or even if they think that they deserved the crime, the state should prosecute the criminal nonetheless. A very usual example is marital violence; many jurisdictions have guidelines forcing the state to prosecute even if the victim does not want to press charges.

So, how long could Deedee Blanchard have been convicted to has no relation at all with those twenty years that you claim were "reduced."

And from [the WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Dee_Dee_Blanchard) it seems that she pleaded guilty, which means that a deal was reached with the DA. She got a reduced sentence, the DA ensured a conviction. Nothing out of the ordinary here.

Maybe the DA thought that the case against her was weak and not good enough to pursue a first-degree murder accusation. Maybe the DA thought the mother abuse could be used as part as a successful insanity defense. Perhaps the DA even feared the jury showing some sympathy for her.

We cannot tell, so the whole "was going to receive 30 years imprisonement" thing is just your opinion.

*1 And certainly all Western countries.

*2 At a practical level, if the victim does not want to press charges, it can help the criminal as either the prosecution feels that they will not be able to get evidence without the victim's testimony, or because they want to concentrate their resources on other crimes. But theoretically it would not matter.

Comment: Not really just my opinion. From my understanding, the boyfriend received the whole 30 years.

Comment: From the WP page, he was the one who actually commit the murder.